# Object has no method 'request' on Meteor

Tags: meteor

I use twitter API on method with Meteor and it return this error :

```
Object [object global] has no method 'request'
```

I don't really understand this error, i don't use this method :/

My code on server folder :

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

    Meteor.methods({

        postTweet: function () {

            const Twit = require('twit');

            const T = new Twit({
                consumer_key: 'xxx', // API key
                consumer_secret: 'xxx', // API secret
                access_token: 'xxx',
                access_token_secret: 'xxx'
            });

            const getTweets = Meteor.wrapAsync(T.get);

            try {

                return getTweets('search/tweets', { q: 'banana since:2011-11-11', count: 100 });

            } catch (error) {

                throw new Meteor.Error(error.name, error.message);

            }

        }

    });

});
```

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I guess you calling `request('twit')`, but in Meteor you have to call `Npm.request('twit')`

Comment: I've edit my first post with my code :)